# Human readable URL Scheme for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ASP site has a database full of events.
Currently, the Action on my Controller for linking to a particular event has a URL like: "mysite.com/events/5"

This is the default behavior, and I'm looking for how to make the URL something more like: "mysite.com/events/some-event-name-that-makes-sense

I have plenty of properties on my event entity that could map to the url, just not sure how to apply it, and how to allow my Action to find it when linking someone to it.

Comment: I checked that post, didn't seem like a dupe to me. Hoping there's a more ASP-oriented solution to it that .NET has built-in.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That question is about PHP. This question is about ASP.NET MVC. This doesn't appear to be a duplicate of that, though the goal is similar.

Comment: Sorry thats my fault.  I thought there was just the one about how SO does it, and didn't see it was a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is called a slug. However, you can't just use any old property on your model to stuff something into the URL. Typically, you'll have a separate property called `Slug` where you will store a URL-safe version of something like the title or name of an object. Once you've done this, it's a simple matter of just using it to generate your URLs and to look up your objects.

For example, where you would have had something like:

```
Url.Action("Events", new { id = item.Id })
```

You'd use instead:

```
Url.Action("Events", new { slug = item.Slug })
```

Then, you modify your action to accept the slug instead of an id and use that to query your event:

```
public ActionResult EventDetail(string slug)
{
    var evt = db.Events.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Slug == slug);

    ...
```

The only slight hitch is you need some way to generate this slug to save it with the rest of the event data. I have the following extension methods I use:

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string s)
{
    s = s ?? string.Empty;
    if (s.Length > 0)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[s.Length];
        int charIndex = 0;

        s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = s[i];
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                chars[charIndex++] = c;
        }

        return new string(chars, 0, charIndex).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
    }

    return s;
}

public static string Slugify(this string s)
{
    s = s ?? string.Empty;
    //First to lower case
    s = s.ToLowerInvariant().RemoveDiacritics();
    //Replace spaces
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s", "-", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    //Remove invalid chars
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-z0-9s\-_]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    //Trim dashes from end
    s = s.Trim('-', '_');
    //Replace double occurences of - or _
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"([\-_]){2,}", "$1", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    return s;
}
```

So, then, you'd just do something like:

```
evt.Slug = evt.Title.Slugify();
```

And/or you can actually make it an editable field in your admin/CMS.

**UPDATE**

JavaScript version

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
MyNamespace.Utilities = {};

MyNamespace.Utilities.RemoveDiacritics = (function () {
    var diacritics = { "\u24B6": "A", "\uFF21": "A", "\u00C0": "A", "\u00C1": "A", "\u00C2": "A", "\u1EA6": "A", "\u1EA4": "A", "\u1EAA": "A", "\u1EA8": "A", "\u00C3": "A", "\u0100": "A", "\u0102": "A", "\u1EB0": "A", "\u1EAE": "A", "\u1EB4": "A", "\u1EB2": "A", "\u0226": "A", "\u01E0": "A", "\u00C4": "A", "\u01DE": "A", "\u1EA2": "A", "\u00C5": "A", "\u01FA": "A", "\u01CD": "A", "\u0200": "A", "\u0202": "A", "\u1EA0": "A", "\u1EAC": "A", "\u1EB6": "A", "\u1E00": "A", "\u0104": "A", "\u023A": "A", "\u2C6F": "A", "\uA732": "AA", "\u00C6": "AE", "\u01FC": "AE", "\u01E2": "AE", "\uA734": "AO", "\uA736": "AU", "\uA738": "AV", "\uA73A": "AV", "\uA73C": "AY", "\u24B7": "B", "\uFF22": "B", "\u1E02": "B", "\u1E04": "B", "\u1E06": "B", "\u0243": "B", "\u0182": "B", "\u0181": "B", "\u24B8": "C", "\uFF23": "C", "\u0106": "C", "\u0108": "C", "\u010A": "C", "\u010C": "C", "\u00C7": "C", "\u1E08": "C", "\u0187": "C", "\u023B": "C", "\uA73E": "C", "\u24B9": "D", "\uFF24": "D", "\u1E0A": "D", "\u010E": "D", "\u1E0C": "D", "\u1E10": "D", "\u1E12": "D", "\u1E0E": "D", "\u0110": "D", "\u018B": "D", "\u018A": "D", "\u0189": "D", "\uA779": "D", "\u01F1": "DZ", "\u01C4": "DZ", "\u01F2": "Dz", "\u01C5": "Dz", "\u24BA": "E", "\uFF25": "E", "\u00C8": "E", "\u00C9": "E", "\u00CA": "E", "\u1EC0": "E", "\u1EBE": "E", "\u1EC4": "E", "\u1EC2": "E", "\u1EBC": "E", "\u0112": "E", "\u1E14": "E", "\u1E16": "E", "\u0114": "E", "\u0116": "E", "\u00CB": "E", "\u1EBA": "E", "\u011A": "E", "\u0204": "E", "\u0206": "E", "\u1EB8": "E", "\u1EC6": "E", "\u0228": "E", "\u1E1C": "E", "\u0118": "E", "\u1E18": "E", "\u1E1A": "E", "\u0190": "E", "\u018E": "E", "\u24BB": "F", "\uFF26": "F", "\u1E1E": "F", "\u0191": "F", "\uA77B": "F", "\u24BC": "G", "\uFF27": "G", "\u01F4": "G", "\u011C": "G", "\u1E20": "G", "\u011E": "G", "\u0120": "G", "\u01E6": "G", "\u0122": "G", "\u01E4": "G", "\u0193": "G", "\uA7A0": "G", "\uA77D": "G", "\uA77E": "G", "\u24BD": "H", "\uFF28": "H", "\u0124": "H", "\u1E22": "H", "\u1E26": "H", "\u021E": "H", "\u1E24": "H", "\u1E28": "H", "\u1E2A": "H", "\u0126": "H", "\u2C67": "H", "\u2C75": "H", "\uA78D": "H", "\u24BE": "I", "\uFF29": "I", "\u00CC": "I", "\u00CD": "I", "\u00CE": "I", "\u0128": "I", "\u012A": "I", "\u012C": "I", "\u0130": "I", "\u00CF": "I", "\u1E2E": "I", "\u1EC8": "I", "\u01CF": "I", "\u0208": "I", "\u020A": "I", "\u1ECA": "I", "\u012E": "I", "\u1E2C": "I", "\u0197": "I", "\u24BF": "J", "\uFF2A": "J", "\u0134": "J", "\u0248": "J", "\u24C0": "K", "\uFF2B": "K", "\u1E30": "K", "\u01E8": "K", "\u1E32": "K", "\u0136": "K", "\u1E34": "K", "\u0198": "K", "\u2C69": "K", "\uA740": "K", "\uA742": "K", "\uA744": "K", "\uA7A2": "K", "\u24C1": "L", "\uFF2C": "L", "\u013F": "L", "\u0139": "L", "\u013D": "L", "\u1E36": "L", "\u1E38": "L", "\u013B": "L", "\u1E3C": "L", "\u1E3A": "L", "\u0141": "L", "\u023D": "L", "\u2C62": "L", "\u2C60": "L", "\uA748": "L", "\uA746": "L", "\uA780": "L", "\u01C7": "LJ", "\u01C8": "Lj", "\u24C2": "M", "\uFF2D": "M", "\u1E3E": "M", "\u1E40": "M", "\u1E42": "M", "\u2C6E": "M", "\u019C": "M", "\u24C3": "N", "\uFF2E": "N", "\u01F8": "N", "\u0143": "N", "\u00D1": "N", "\u1E44": "N", "\u0147": "N", "\u1E46": "N", "\u0145": "N", "\u1E4A": "N", "\u1E48": "N", "\u0220": "N", "\u019D": "N", "\uA790": "N", "\uA7A4": "N", "\u01CA": "NJ", "\u01CB": "Nj", "\u24C4": "O", "\uFF2F": "O", "\u00D2": "O", "\u00D3": "O", "\u00D4": "O", "\u1ED2": "O", "\u1ED0": "O", "\u1ED6": "O", "\u1ED4": "O", "\u00D5": "O", "\u1E4C": "O", "\u022C": "O", "\u1E4E": "O", "\u014C": "O", "\u1E50": "O", "\u1E52": "O", "\u014E": "O", "\u022E": "O", "\u0230": "O", "\u00D6": "O", "\u022A": "O", "\u1ECE": "O", "\u0150": "O", "\u01D1": "O", "\u020C": "O", "\u020E": "O", "\u01A0": "O", "\u1EDC": "O", "\u1EDA": "O", "\u1EE0": "O", "\u1EDE": "O", "\u1EE2": "O", "\u1ECC": "O", "\u1ED8": "O", "\u01EA": "O", "\u01EC": "O", "\u00D8": "O", "\u01FE": "O", "\u0186": "O", "\u019F": "O", "\uA74A": "O", "\uA74C": "O", "\u0152": "OE", "\u01A2": "OI", "\uA74E": "OO", "\u0222": "OU", "\u24C5": "P", "\uFF30": "P", "\u1E54": "P", "\u1E56": "P", "\u01A4": "P", "\u2C63": "P", "\uA750": "P", "\uA752": "P", "\uA754": "P", "\u24C6": "Q", "\uFF31": "Q", "\uA756": "Q", "\uA758": "Q", "\u024A": "Q", "\u24C7": "R", "\uFF32": "R", "\u0154": "R", "\u1E58": "R", "\u0158": "R", "\u0210": "R", "\u0212": "R", "\u1E5A": "R", "\u1E5C": "R", "\u0156": "R", "\u1E5E": "R", "\u024C": "R", "\u2C64": "R", "\uA75A": "R", "\uA7A6": "R", "\uA782": "R", "\u24C8": "S", "\uFF33": "S", "\u015A": "S", "\u1E64": "S", "\u015C": "S", "\u1E60": "S", "\u0160": "S", "\u1E66": "S", "\u1E62": "S", "\u1E68": "S", "\u0218": "S", "\u015E": "S", "\u2C7E": "S", "\uA7A8": "S", "\uA784": "S", "\u1E9E": "SS", "\u24C9": "T", "\uFF34": "T", "\u1E6A": "T", "\u0164": "T", "\u1E6C": "T", "\u021A": "T", "\u0162": "T", "\u1E70": "T", "\u1E6E": "T", "\u0166": "T", "\u01AC": "T", "\u01AE": "T", "\u023E": "T", "\uA786": "T", "\uA728": "TZ", "\u24CA": "U", "\uFF35": "U", "\u00D9": "U", "\u00DA": "U", "\u00DB": "U", "\u0168": "U", "\u1E78": "U", "\u016A": "U", "\u1E7A": "U", "\u016C": "U", "\u00DC": "U", "\u01DB": "U", "\u01D7": "U", "\u01D5": "U", "\u01D9": "U", "\u1EE6": "U", "\u016E": "U", "\u0170": "U", "\u01D3": "U", "\u0214": "U", "\u0216": "U", "\u01AF": "U", "\u1EEA": "U", "\u1EE8": "U", "\u1EEE": "U", "\u1EEC": "U", "\u1EF0": "U", "\u1EE4": "U", "\u1E72": "U", "\u0172": "U", "\u1E76": "U", "\u1E74": "U", "\u0244": "U", "\u24CB": "V", "\uFF36": "V", "\u1E7C": "V", "\u1E7E": "V", "\u01B2": "V", "\uA75E": "V", "\u0245": "V", "\uA760": "VY", "\u24CC": "W", "\uFF37": "W", "\u1E80": "W", "\u1E82": "W", "\u0174": "W", "\u1E86": "W", "\u1E84": "W", "\u1E88": "W", "\u2C72": "W", "\u24CD": "X", "\uFF38": "X", "\u1E8A": "X", "\u1E8C": "X", "\u24CE": "Y", "\uFF39": "Y", "\u1EF2": "Y", "\u00DD": "Y", "\u0176": "Y", "\u1EF8": "Y", "\u0232": "Y", "\u1E8E": "Y", "\u0178": "Y", "\u1EF6": "Y", "\u1EF4": "Y", "\u01B3": "Y", "\u024E": "Y", "\u1EFE": "Y", "\u24CF": "Z", "\uFF3A": "Z", "\u0179": "Z", "\u1E90": "Z", "\u017B": "Z", "\u017D": "Z", "\u1E92": "Z", "\u1E94": "Z", "\u01B5": "Z", "\u0224": "Z", "\u2C7F": "Z", "\u2C6B": "Z", "\uA762": "Z", "\u24D0": "a", "\uFF41": "a", "\u1E9A": "a", "\u00E0": "a", "\u00E1": "a", "\u00E2": "a", "\u1EA7": "a", "\u1EA5": "a", "\u1EAB": "a", "\u1EA9": "a", "\u00E3": "a", "\u0101": "a", "\u0103": "a", "\u1EB1": "a", "\u1EAF": "a", "\u1EB5": "a", "\u1EB3": "a", "\u0227": "a", "\u01E1": "a", "\u00E4": "a", "\u01DF": "a", "\u1EA3": "a", "\u00E5": "a", "\u01FB": "a", "\u01CE": "a", "\u0201": "a", "\u0203": "a", "\u1EA1": "a", "\u1EAD": "a", "\u1EB7": "a", "\u1E01": "a", "\u0105": "a", "\u2C65": "a", "\u0250": "a", "\uA733": "aa", "\u00E6": "ae", "\u01FD": "ae", "\u01E3": "ae", "\uA735": "ao", "\uA737": "au", "\uA739": "av", "\uA73B": "av", "\uA73D": "ay", "\u24D1": "b", "\uFF42": "b", "\u1E03": "b", "\u1E05": "b", "\u1E07": "b", "\u0180": "b", "\u0183": "b", "\u0253": "b", "\u24D2": "c", "\uFF43": "c", "\u0107": "c", "\u0109": "c", "\u010B": "c", "\u010D": "c", "\u00E7": "c", "\u1E09": "c", "\u0188": "c", "\u023C": "c", "\uA73F": "c", "\u2184": "c", "\u24D3": "d", "\uFF44": "d", "\u1E0B": "d", "\u010F": "d", "\u1E0D": "d", "\u1E11": "d", "\u1E13": "d", "\u1E0F": "d", "\u0111": "d", "\u018C": "d", "\u0256": "d", "\u0257": "d", "\uA77A": "d", "\u01F3": "dz", "\u01C6": "dz", "\u24D4": "e", "\uFF45": "e", "\u00E8": "e", "\u00E9": "e", "\u00EA": "e", "\u1EC1": "e", "\u1EBF": "e", "\u1EC5": "e", "\u1EC3": "e", "\u1EBD": "e", "\u0113": "e", "\u1E15": "e", "\u1E17": "e", "\u0115": "e", "\u0117": "e", "\u00EB": "e", "\u1EBB": "e", "\u011B": "e", "\u0205": "e", "\u0207": "e", "\u1EB9": "e", "\u1EC7": "e", "\u0229": "e", "\u1E1D": "e", "\u0119": "e", "\u1E19": "e", "\u1E1B": "e", "\u0247": "e", "\u025B": "e", "\u01DD": "e", "\u24D5": "f", "\uFF46": "f", "\u1E1F": "f", "\u0192": "f", "\uA77C": "f", "\u24D6": "g", "\uFF47": "g", "\u01F5": "g", "\u011D": "g", "\u1E21": "g", "\u011F": "g", "\u0121": "g", "\u01E7": "g", "\u0123": "g", "\u01E5": "g", "\u0260": "g", "\uA7A1": "g", "\u1D79": "g", "\uA77F": "g", "\u24D7": "h", "\uFF48": "h", "\u0125": "h", "\u1E23": "h", "\u1E27": "h", "\u021F": "h", "\u1E25": "h", "\u1E29": "h", "\u1E2B": "h", "\u1E96": "h", "\u0127": "h", "\u2C68": "h", "\u2C76": "h", "\u0265": "h", "\u0195": "hv", "\u24D8": "i", "\uFF49": "i", "\u00EC": "i", "\u00ED": "i", "\u00EE": "i", "\u0129": "i", "\u012B": "i", "\u012D": "i", "\u00EF": "i", "\u1E2F": "i", "\u1EC9": "i", "\u01D0": "i", "\u0209": "i", "\u020B": "i", "\u1ECB": "i", "\u012F": "i", "\u1E2D": "i", "\u0268": "i", "\u0131": "i", "\u24D9": "j", "\uFF4A": "j", "\u0135": "j", "\u01F0": "j", "\u0249": "j", "\u24DA": "k", "\uFF4B": "k", "\u1E31": "k", "\u01E9": "k", "\u1E33": "k", "\u0137": "k", "\u1E35": "k", "\u0199": "k", "\u2C6A": "k", "\uA741": "k", "\uA743": "k", "\uA745": "k", "\uA7A3": "k", "\u24DB": "l", "\uFF4C": "l", "\u0140": "l", "\u013A": "l", "\u013E": "l", "\u1E37": "l", "\u1E39": "l", "\u013C": "l", "\u1E3D": "l", "\u1E3B": "l", "\u0142": "l", "\u019A": "l", "\u026B": "l", "\u2C61": "l", "\uA749": "l", "\uA781": "l", "\uA747": "l", "\u01C9": "lj", "\u24DC": "m", "\uFF4D": "m", "\u1E3F": "m", "\u1E41": "m", "\u1E43": "m", "\u0271": "m", "\u026F": "m", "\u24DD": "n", "\uFF4E": "n", "\u01F9": "n", "\u0144": "n", "\u00F1": "n", "\u1E45": "n", "\u0148": "n", "\u1E47": "n", "\u0146": "n", "\u1E4B": "n", "\u1E49": "n", "\u019E": "n", "\u0272": "n", "\u0149": "n", "\uA791": "n", "\uA7A5": "n", "\u01CC": "nj", "\u24DE": "o", "\uFF4F": "o", "\u00F2": "o", "\u00F3": "o", "\u00F4": "o", "\u1ED3": "o", "\u1ED1": "o", "\u1ED7": "o", "\u1ED5": "o", "\u00F5": "o", "\u1E4D": "o", "\u022D": "o", "\u1E4F": "o", "\u014D": "o", "\u1E51": "o", "\u1E53": "o", "\u014F": "o", "\u022F": "o", "\u0231": "o", "\u00F6": "o", "\u022B": "o", "\u1ECF": "o", "\u0151": "o", "\u01D2": "o", "\u020D": "o", "\u020F": "o", "\u01A1": "o", "\u1EDD": "o", "\u1EDB": "o", "\u1EE1": "o", "\u1EDF": "o", "\u1EE3": "o", "\u1ECD": "o", "\u1ED9": "o", "\u01EB": "o", "\u01ED": "o", "\u00F8": "o", "\u01FF": "o", "\u0254": "o", "\uA74B": "o", "\uA74D": "o", "\u0275": "o", "\u0153": "oe", "\u0276": "oe", "\u01A3": "oi", "\u0223": "ou", "\uA74F": "oo", "\u24DF": "p", "\uFF50": "p", "\u1E55": "p", "\u1E57": "p", "\u01A5": "p", "\u1D7D": "p", "\uA751": "p", "\uA753": "p", "\uA755": "p", "\u24E0": "q", "\uFF51": "q", "\u024B": "q", "\uA757": "q", "\uA759": "q", "\u24E1": "r", "\uFF52": "r", "\u0155": "r", "\u1E59": "r", "\u0159": "r", "\u0211": "r", "\u0213": "r", "\u1E5B": "r", "\u1E5D": "r", "\u0157": "r", "\u1E5F": "r", "\u024D": "r", "\u027D": "r", "\uA75B": "r", "\uA7A7": "r", "\uA783": "r", "\u24E2": "s", "\uFF53": "s", "\u015B": "s", "\u1E65": "s", "\u015D": "s", "\u1E61": "s", "\u0161": "s", "\u1E67": "s", "\u1E63": "s", "\u1E69": "s", "\u0219": "s", "\u015F": "s", "\u023F": "s", "\uA7A9": "s", "\uA785": "s", "\u017F": "s", "\u1E9B": "s", "\u00DF": "ss", "\u24E3": "t", "\uFF54": "t", "\u1E6B": "t", "\u1E97": "t", "\u0165": "t", "\u1E6D": "t", "\u021B": "t", "\u0163": "t", "\u1E71": "t", "\u1E6F": "t", "\u0167": "t", "\u01AD": "t", "\u0288": "t", "\u2C66": "t", "\uA787": "t", "\uA729": "tz", "\u24E4": "u", "\uFF55": "u", "\u00F9": "u", "\u00FA": "u", "\u00FB": "u", "\u0169": "u", "\u1E79": "u", "\u016B": "u", "\u1E7B": "u", "\u016D": "u", "\u00FC": "u", "\u01DC": "u", "\u01D8": "u", "\u01D6": "u", "\u01DA": "u", "\u1EE7": "u", "\u016F": "u", "\u0171": "u", "\u01D4": "u", "\u0215": "u", "\u0217": "u", "\u01B0": "u", "\u1EEB": "u", "\u1EE9": "u", "\u1EEF": "u", "\u1EED": "u", "\u1EF1": "u", "\u1EE5": "u", "\u1E73": "u", "\u0173": "u", "\u1E77": "u", "\u1E75": "u", "\u0289": "u", "\u24E5": "v", "\uFF56": "v", "\u1E7D": "v", "\u1E7F": "v", "\u028B": "v", "\uA75F": "v", "\u028C": "v", "\uA761": "vy", "\u24E6": "w", "\uFF57": "w", "\u1E81": "w", "\u1E83": "w", "\u0175": "w", "\u1E87": "w", "\u1E85": "w", "\u1E98": "w", "\u1E89": "w", "\u2C73": "w", "\u24E7": "x", "\uFF58": "x", "\u1E8B": "x", "\u1E8D": "x", "\u24E8": "y", "\uFF59": "y", "\u1EF3": "y", "\u00FD": "y", "\u0177": "y", "\u1EF9": "y", "\u0233": "y", "\u1E8F": "y", "\u00FF": "y", "\u1EF7": "y", "\u1E99": "y", "\u1EF5": "y", "\u01B4": "y", "\u024F": "y", "\u1EFF": "y", "\u24E9": "z", "\uFF5A": "z", "\u017A": "z", "\u1E91": "z", "\u017C": "z", "\u017E": "z", "\u1E93": "z", "\u1E95": "z", "\u01B6": "z", "\u0225": "z", "\u0240": "z", "\u2C6C": "z", "\uA763": "z", "\uFF10": "0", "\u2080": "0", "\u24EA": "0", "\u2070": "0", "\u00B9": "1", "\u2474": "1", "\u2081": "1", "\u2776": "1", "\u24F5": "1", "\u2488": "1", "\u2460": "1", "\uFF11": "1", "\u00B2": "2", "\u2777": "2", "\u2475": "2", "\uFF12": "2", "\u2082": "2", "\u24F6": "2", "\u2461": "2", "\u2489": "2", "\u00B3": "3", "\uFF13": "3", "\u248A": "3", "\u2476": "3", "\u2083": "3", "\u2778": "3", "\u24F7": "3", "\u2462": "3", "\u24F8": "4", "\u2463": "4", "\u248B": "4", "\uFF14": "4", "\u2074": "4", "\u2084": "4", "\u2779": "4", "\u2477": "4", "\u248C": "5", "\u2085": "5", "\u24F9": "5", "\u2478": "5", "\u277A": "5", "\u2464": "5", "\uFF15": "5", "\u2075": "5", "\u2479": "6", "\u2076": "6", "\uFF16": "6", "\u277B": "6", "\u2086": "6", "\u2465": "6", "\u24FA": "6", "\u248D": "6", "\uFF17": "7", "\u2077": "7", "\u277C": "7", "\u24FB": "7", "\u248E": "7", "\u2087": "7", "\u247A": "7", "\u2466": "7", "\u2467": "8", "\u248F": "8", "\u24FC": "8", "\u247B": "8", "\u2078": "8", "\uFF18": "8", "\u277D": "8", "\u2088": "8", "\u24FD": "9", "\uFF19": "9", "\u2490": "9", "\u277E": "9", "\u247C": "9", "\u2089": "9", "\u2468": "9", "\u2079": "9" };
    return function (str) {
        if (typeof (str) == "undefined") return '';
        var chars = str.split(''),
            i = chars.length - 1,
            alter = false,
            ch;
        for (; i >= 0; i--) {
            ch = chars[i];
            if (diacritics.hasOwnProperty(ch)) {
                chars[i] = diacritics[ch];
                alter = true;
            }
        }
        if (alter) {
            str = chars.join('');
        }
        return str;
    }
})();

MyNamespace.Utilities.Slugify = function (input) {
    if (input == null) input = '';
    return MyNamespace.Utilities.RemoveDiacritics(input)
        .replace(/^\s\s*/, '') // Trim start
        .replace(/\s\s*$/, '') // Trim end
        .toLowerCase() // Camel case is bad
        .replace(/[^a-z0-9_\-\s]+/g, '') // Exchange invalid chars
        .replace(/[\-\s_]+/g, '-'); // Swap whitespace for single hyphen
}
```

Comment: I actually have a JavaScript version I use as well for auto-filling the field as a user types something like a title. See update.

Comment: Ah yes, that would save the need for server involvement. Wish I could upvote this twice...

Comment: Chris, would you keep an overload of EventDetails(int id) that did a permanent redirect to EventDetails(string slug) after looking up the item based on the incoming Id? (would result in two queries), but may help with SEO?

Comment: If you want to make both ways available, that's fine but I wouldn't worry about redirecting automatically. On the view for both, just add a canonical link meta tag pointing to the slug version. That's enough to satisfy the SEO.