# MVC Creating Virtual Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

**Part 1**

I am creating an MVC Web site that pulls articles from a database. I am trying to replicate one of the features of WordPress. My main URL looks like "http://127.0.0.1/Articles/Index". I could easily create a URL that would load the article: "http://127.0.0.1/Articles/Index?id=1234".

But that URL isn't going to be very good for search engines, so I would like to create a virtual URL: "http://127.0.0.1/Articles/Index/Computer-Science/Machine-Language".

This would load the article titled Machine Language from the Computer Science category, in the database. There will be a Virtual URL "/computer-science/machine-language" in the database.

Anyway, my code works fine, it pulls the correct article out of the database, but instead of displaying the article, the browser displays a 404 error, because "/Computer-Science/Machine-Language" doesn't actually exist.

So my question is, how do I stop the browser from throwing 404 errors? The browser is thinking it's a real URL but the URL only exists in my database.

**Part 2**

I also have 2 other questions that go with this. First, is there a way that I can remove the Index from the URL? So it's just /Articles/Computer-Science/Machine-Language?

Second, is there anyway I can force the URLs to all be lower case? MVC seems to use capital letters in my URLS, and I don't like it. I've been told it messes with SEO because Google sees /computer-science and /Computer-Science as two different URLs with duplicate data and they penalize my site.

Thank You.

Comment: This can all be handled through MVC routing: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Human readable URL Scheme for ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324139/human-readable-url-scheme-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I was able to solve it using routing. I'll post my solution to help someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using multiple routing methods.

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Article",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}/{article}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", category = "", article = "" }
        );
```

Comment: FYI - You shouldn't set default values for `category` or `article`. If you do, they will not be required parameters. Also, once you do that, it is better to put your custom route before the default route, since they are run in order from top to bottom and should be in order from most specific to least specific.